# Using MapPoint from Jacob (java com)

Tags: java, widget, ocx, jacob, mappoint

I need to create in java a widget with a MapPoint element.
I found a tutorial to open Mapoint Application and using function.
But i didn't found any to integrate it in a widget. 
How can integrate it in a widget?

EDIT: I can use an other free library for java com, jacob is not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Jacob so I don't know if it does this; but you are going to need to use a COM Bridge that supports Active X controls.